# Copy and paste columns between sheets based on an Excel "Map" or table? - Further autoexecute file links?

Tags: excel, automation, mapping, vba

I have been doing this manually for far too long, and I feel there must be a way to speed up this process. Hopefully you guys can help me.

Currently I have an excel file that has written in VBA macros that copy and paste certain columns from one sheet and paste them into another sheet. There are about 160 of these written, each with about 10 copy/paste commands. (This workbook is called `workbook A`)

Currently my method involves me opening up `Workbook B`, copying the data into a sheet in `Workbook A`, selecting a macro to run from a dropdown in `Workbook A`, copying the results and pasting them into a "master" `Workbook C`. The problem for me is that There are frequent instances when maps - that is the column locations of data - change in `Workbook B`. I maintain a "master map" file that looks something like this:

```
Contract# | Purchaser | Price | Quantity | Total
------------------------------------------------
A         |  B        |  C    |  D       |  E
------------------------------------------------
G         |  D        |  C    |  A       |  B
------------------------------------------------
```

etc. (Apologies if that's messy)

What I would like to do is have the sheet do the copying and pasting automatically based on A: The column on the map (the pasting column) and B: the letter represented in the row for that particular Contract (this copies the column of which the letter represented).

Is this possible?

Secondly, if that is - The option to have this execute automatically by specifying the file patch of each file would be outstanding (I have a clear taxonomy of file locations and names). Is that also possible?

- Added condensed sample of ran macro.

The macro is quite simple, here is a sample...

```
 Sub PA979()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'Retail $
    Sheets("VSR Input").Select
   Range("x1:x5004").Copy
   Sheets("Sheet1").Select
   Range("q4").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste

   'PA $
    Sheets("VSR Input").Select
   Range("y1:y5004").Copy
   Sheets("Sheet1").Select
   Range("s4").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste

'Q
    Sheets("VSR Input").Select
   Range("z1:z5004").Copy
   Sheets("Sheet1").Select
   Range("t4").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste

   'Total $
    Sheets("VSR Input").Select
   Range("aa1:aa5004").Copy
   Sheets("Sheet1").Select
   Range("u4").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Range("A1").Select

    Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim usedRows As Long
usedRows = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("v3").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PA#"
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
   ActiveCell = "979"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(usedRows - 3, 1)), Type:= _
        xlFillDefault
        Range("v4").Select
        Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

End Sub `
```

Comment: All of that is possible - is there some exact part of it which is giving you problems?  It would help to post a (small but representative) part of the current macro - this will make your current process a little clearer...

Comment: `Workbook A` (contains all your macros), `Workbook B` (this is a source workbook, there are many), `Workbook C` (a single workbook, where you consolidate all your results). Your macros in `Workbook A` re-order the columns of the source data, so that you can paste it into `Workbook C`.  Is this what your current process is? (your question is a little hard to understand)

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. To Nick's question - yes that is pretty much the process. I Copy source data into `Workbook A`, Run macro to sort, paste sorted data into `workbook C`.

Comment: updated question with sample macro code Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumes the workbook containing the macro has a worksheet "map" with one row for each contract number:

A: contract number
B: file path for the input workbook
C-F: source column letters for each of the columns being copied

Row 2 on the Map sheet has the destination column letters in cols C-F

Compiled but not tested:

```
Option Explicit


Sub Tester()
    CopyData 979
End Sub



Sub CopyData(contractNumber)

Dim wbInput As Workbook
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim shtIn As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet, shtMap As Worksheet
Dim usedRows As Long
Dim arrDestCols, x As Integer, cFrom, cTo
Dim f As Range, mapRow As Range

    'has the column mapping info for each contract number
    Set shtMap = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Map")
    'find the row for this contract number
    Set f = shtMap.Range("A3:A100").Find(contractNumber, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If f Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "contract number " & contractNumber & " not found!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set mapRow = f.EntireRow
    End If

    'assumes input file path is in column B
    Set wbInput = Workbooks.Open(mapRow.Cells(2).Value)
    Set shtIn = wbInput.Sheets("VSR Input")

    Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Set shtDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For x = 1 To 4
        ' "source" column letters are in columns C-F of the found row
        cFrom = mapRow.Cells(2 + x).Value
        ' "destination" column letters are in C2:F2 of the Map sheet
        cTo = shtMap.Rows(2).Cells(2 + x).Value
        shtIn.Range(cFrom & "1").Resize(5004, 1).Copy shtDest.Range(cTo & "4")
    Next x

    With shtDest
        usedRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("v3").Value = contractNumber
        .Range("v4").Resize(usedRows - 3, 1).Value = contractNumber
    End With

    wbInput.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks like what im after. I might need to do some editing to it to fit. Right now i have a Subscript out of range (Error 9) on ` Set shtIn = wbInput.Sheets("VSR Input") `

Comment: There is no sheet named "VSR Input" in your source workbook - you will have to edit that...  Or use `Sheets(1)` if data is always going to be on the first sheet.